# Smallest n numbers from a list

Tags: python, list

If I have a list `list1=[1,15,9,3,6,21,10,11]` how do I obtain the smallest 2 integers from that?

`min()` gives me one number, but what about 2?

Comment: what should `[1,1,2,3,4,5]` output?

Comment: Ideally `[1,2]` but I don't have duplicates in the list.

Comment: Do you care about performance or simplicity?

Comment: @PasArif, if you had then a heapq would not work

Comment: @JeremyWest performance

Comment: A linear pass is probably fastest if you only need two elements.

Comment: @PasArif, it can be done in a single pass as per the last part of my answer which is about as efficient as you will get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import [heapq](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html)

```
import heapq

list1=[1,15,9,3,6,21,10,11]

print(heapq.nsmallest(2,list1))
```

The limitation with that is if you have a repeated value let's say `l=[1,3,5,1]`, the two smallest values will be `[1,1]`.

Edit 1:

```
In [2]:
    list1=[1,15,9,3,6,21,10,11]

In [3]:

    %timeit sorted(list1)[:2]
    1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.58 µs per loop
In [5]:

    import heapq
    %timeit heapq.nsmallest(2,list1)
    100000 loops, best of 3: 4.18 µs per loop
```

From the two, it seems sorting the list is faster for smaller sets.

Edit 2:

```
In [14]:

    import random
    list1=[[random.random() for i in range(100)] for j in range(100)]
In [15]:

    %timeit sorted(list1)[:2]
    10000 loops, best of 3: 55.6 µs per loop
In [16]:

    import heapq
    %timeit heapq.nsmallest(2,list1)
    10000 loops, best of 3: 27.7 µs per loop
```

Thanks to Padraic Cunningham, `heapq` is faster with larger sets

Comment: `nsmallest` Leb. He's looking for the smallest.

Comment: run it on a large list, running on a handful of elements is not very informative

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'll give it a try and update in a sec

Comment: So basically you're saying that my solution is faster, thank you :) BTW, the second option that I provided is probably even faster because it requires 3 passes, where `sort` (usually) requires more.

Comment: @alfasin I'm not gonna lie, if it's faster it's faster

Comment: Thanks for comparing the answers

Comment: No worries, he `O(n log n)` becomes more apparent when you deal with larger data sets, nsmallest I think is s something like  `O(n * log k ))`, if you use  `list1=[random.random()  for j in range(10**5)]` the difference will be even greater, the size of k  is quite important though, if `k = 10000` then sorted and slicing would probably be faster

Answer (score 4):

You can sort the list and grab the first two elements:

```
sorted(list1)[:2]
```

Or, remove the min and find the next min (which should be the quickest solution for large datasets because it requires 3 passes at most):

```
list1=[1,15,9,3,6,21,10,11]
m1 = min(list1)
list1.remove(m1)
m2 = min(list1)
print m1, m2 # 1 3
```

Comment: It can be done in two passes using min or one pass as per the last part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using min and two passes over list1:

```
list1=[1,15,9,3,6,21,10,11]
mn = min(list1)
mn2 = min(i for i  in list1 if i != mn)    
print((mn,mn2))
(1, 3)
```

It `list1=[1,1,9,3,6,21,10,11]` where the smallest was a dupe, his would still return `1,3` where nsmallest would return `1,1` so that is something to be aware of.

You can also do it in one pass over the list since you have no dupes:

```
def min_two(lst):
    mn1, mn2 = float("inf"),float("inf")
    for ele in lst:
        if ele < mn1:
            mn1 = ele
            continue
        if ele < mn2:
            mn2 = ele
    return mn1, mn2
```

Which will be faster than a `heapq.nsmallest`:

```
In [34]:list1=[random.random()  for j in range(10**5)]

In [35]: timeit  heapq.nsmallest(2,list1)             
100 loops, best of 3: 11.6 ms per loop

In [36]: timeit min_two(list1)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.01 ms per loop

In [37]:  %timeit sorted(list1)[:2]
10 loops, best of 3: 42.2 ms per l
```

And if you did actually want to handle dupes:

```
def min_two_dupes(lst):
    mn1, mn2 = float("inf"),float("inf")
    for ele in lst:
        if ele < mn1:
            mn1 = ele
            continue
        if ele < mn2 and ele != mn1:
            mn2 = ele
    return mn1, mn2
```

Which will get the two lowest numbers ignoring repeats:

```
In [48]: list1 = [12, 15, 3, 3, 6, 21, 10, 11]

In [49]: min_two_dupes(list1)
Out[49]: (3, 6)
```

And runs just as efficiently:

```
In [52]: timeit min_two_dupes(list1)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.04 ms per loop
```

Comment: indeed, it can be done in one pass as you suggested, I was too lazy... :)

Answer (score 1):

you want the n first or 2 first? this is one way to get the 2 first lowest numbers in a list:

```
list1=[1,15,9,3,6,21,10,11]
list1.sort()
twoFirst = list1[:2]
nFirst = list1[:n]
```

I am probably deleting my answer as someone suggested while I was writing my answer. This was return the same number multiple times if there are relevant duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If your list can't contain duplicates, you could use heapq:

```
from heapq import nsmallest
list1=[1,15,9,3,6,21,10,11] 
smallest = nsmallest(2, list1)
```

If it can, you could sort the list and then slice it:

```
smallest = sorted(list1)[0:2]
```

Comment: Of the two, which one is faster?

Comment: Tried to update apparently can't, thank you for providing both options